# Batch findstr error

Tags: batch-file, findstr

I am trying to make a Database of how much I paid for Items, so I can quickly find it when selling them again. I now have a batch file that automatically stores the Item name, and for how much I bought it. (works fine)
Now I wanted to make another batch file where I can enter a name of an item and have it tell me if I have it is in my database, and how much I paid for it.
I just messed around with the findstr command, and this was created (i know its bad :D). But it always says: FINDSTR:*searchterm* can not be opened.
Any Ideas?

```
@echo off

:start

set /p item=Item you want to look up: 
findstr /I / X "%item%" log.txt > logoutput.txt


goto start

pause
```

Comment: The `pause` command will be never reached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an space between the slash and the X (`/ X`) that should not be present.

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it, but when I enter a search term it just goes back to start, kinda. It doesn't give an error, but it also doesn't write anything in the output file (the item i am searching if in the log file) :/

Comment: @Schmix, the `/X` ask for a exact match in the lines. That is, the search term and the full line must be equal. I think it is better to use `/I /C:"%item%"`

Comment: Now it's working perfectly, but is it possible to print the output to the screen? Just wondering

Comment: @Schmix, not in only one step without a third party utility or a lot of batch code. If you need the output file (if not just remove the redirection), the easiest way is to first execute the `findstr` redirected to the file and then `type logoutput.txt` to show the result of the `findstr`